# How to split logs according to patterns?

Tags: logging, scripting, log-files

I would like to be able to split log files according to a pattern found in them.

For example process all logs and look for `/(\w+)\s` to match `/myresource` but exclude `/myresource/anythingelse`, to redirect everything to `/var/log/extractedlog/myresource/access.log`. I could easily script this using a bit of grep however, trying to do this in real time could make the problem harder. For example, I would like to call the program twice without generating duplicates.

**EDIT**

Here is a complete code to get something like this working with syslog-ng `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` (credits get to the accepted answer):

```
# no-parse let syslog load any source
source s_unparsed_source {
    file("/var/log/myservice/access.log"
        flags(no-parse));
};

# Just protect the input and avoid syslog-ng header to be added in the final log
template t_preserve_message {
    template("$MSG\n");
    template_escape(no);
};

# This will filter the message only matching the given expression
filter f_match_pattern1 {
    match("\/pattern1");
};

destination d_target1 {
    file("/var/log/target/pattern1/access.log" template(t_preserve_message));
};

# The actual logging instruction which wraps everything
log {
    source(s_unparsed_source);
    filter(f_math_pattern1);
    destination(d_target1);
};
```

Comment: rsyslog will do this natively.

Comment: Also syslog-ng.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `rsyslog` and `syslog-ng` (the two usual programs used in GNU/Linux to manage logs) have means to do this.

With `syslog-ng`, you can define filters that [match a regular expression](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.4-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.4-guide-admin/html/regular-expr.html):

```
filter myfilter {
  not match("regex" value("\/usr\/sbin\/run-crons"))
  and not match("regex" value("vmware-checker"));
}
```

And you can also use the [pattern database](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.4-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.4-guide-admin/html/concepts-pattern-databases.html), which allows correlation of events and action triggering.

There's also [logstash](http://logstash.net/), which has [advanced filtering capabilities](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/). Specifically, it has a [`grep`](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grep) filter:

```
filter {
  grep {
    match => { "message" => "hello world" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Logsurfer](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/logsurfer/).

I use syslog-ng for "normal" logging into files and in addition I pipe everything into logsurfer for classification by program and to spot new/unusual messages.

A snippet from my config so I see all openvpn warnings:

```
'^.{29} .+ openvpn\[[0-9]+\]: (ERROR|WARN)' - - - 0 echo >>lines.openvpn $0
'^.{29} .+ openvpn\[[0-9]+\]: ' - - - 0 ignore
```